# Rails: upload cvs file to process it as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, hash

I have this model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :csvFile_file_name
  has_attached_file :csvFile, :path => ":rails_root/public/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
  serialize :content, Hash

  #after_save :do_cvs_process

  def do_csv_process
    product = {}
    FasterCSV.foreach(self.csvFile.path, :headers => true, :col_sep => ",") do |row|    
       row.to_hash.each do |key, value| 
         product[key.underscore.to_sym] = value
       end
     end
     self.update_column(:content, {:first => product})
  end
end
```

I have several problems:

1. Because of standard browser security, I have to upload file and save it before processing it with csv to assign it as a hash to my `:content` attribute... That's why I'm using update_column to avoid callbacks. Is there a clever way to do it?
2. It does not work! When back to the view `<%= @survey.content %>` rails tells me that it found an array when it expected a hash.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What have you looked at? Have you googled "rails file upload"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not remove your question just because you have solved it. Your answer should be posted as an answer, not edited into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.import_csv_file(iFileName)
  c = CSV.open iFileName
  header= c.first.map{ |i| i.to_s.strip.downcase; }        
  c.each { |row|  import_hash( Hash[*header.zip(row).flatten] ); }
  c.close    
end
```

My product class has an import_hash method that looks for lowercase/spacefree headers and matches them to fields in the product.

```
product.name = hash['productname'] || hash['name']   #for example.
```

Answer (score -2):

use faster_csv gem. Here are some quick links:

[SOURCE] https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv

[DOCS] http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

[CHEATSHEET]http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/faster_csv/

Please do some R&D on GitHub before pasting a questions, these questions are already there.

Comment: Hum hum, ok I understand my question has 2 in one so met me edit it so it's clearer and you may not answer aside ^_^

Comment: faster_csv is part of rails 3 and it can be accessed under `CSV` only